# Definition of Concave set

Tags: definition, convex-geometry

We know that a set is convex if the straight line joining any two points of the set lies completely in the set. Or, mathematically, a set $X$ is convex if

$$x_1, x_2 \in X, 0 \leq \lambda \leq 1 \Longrightarrow\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2 \in X$$

But how do we define a **concave** set? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 7):

There is no such thing as a concave set, since the definition of the convexity of a set is different from the convexity of a function.

Comment: Can you provide a reference ?

Comment: @Shailesh There are many books in which you will find no definition of a concave set.

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Non-convex_set) basically says this.

Comment: Couldn't you extend the definition of a concave polygon to sets?

Answer (score 2):

A set is concave if and only if its complement is convex.

Comment: So, empty set is both concave and convex?

Comment: @Boby Even a halfspace is.