# How is a concave set defined?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I thought that there are no concave sets but then I came across this definition on Wolfram.

A set in $R^d$ is concave if it does not contain all the line segments connecting any pair of its points.

reference: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Concave.html

Since I am finding no other reference to concave sets, I am wondering: Is this wrong?

Greetings,

Steffen

A related question is here [Definition of Concave set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1696787/definition-of-concave-set)

Comment: Can you edit the title so that it is a question and not just your name?

Comment: Wikipedia has a similar definition as Wolfram (concave = not convex), but advises against using this term https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set#Non-convex_set So the most correct answer seems to be: "There is no such thing as a concave set."

Comment: I had thought a set was concave if it wasn't convex. And as mentioned, convex means every line connecting points within the set are themselves within the set.

Comment: It makes some kind of sense that "concave" means "not convex", but then you find that, for example, a set containing exactly two points is concave. That seems weird. I think things like that might be why people don't like to use the term *concave set*.

Comment: I might call a set concave if its complement is convex. At a glance that seems reasonable but I can't back that up with evidence of it being in use as a term or evidence of it being a useful notion

Comment: @FShrike I have seen a definition of concave functions, which I think is related to your idea.